# Using word wildcards to find unaccepted changes

Tags: vba, ms-word, wildcard

I have some word documents with unaccepted, tracked changes. I want to accept them but still have them shown in red in my documents. I think a good way to do this would be doing a wildcard search for unaccepted changes and replacing them with the same text in red, however I dont know if this is possible.
I am also happy with other ways of achieving my goal, without wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Applying formatting to revisions cannot be done using Word's standard find & replace operation. However, you can write a macro that enumerates all revisions and then applies formatting to each of them.

There is a bloc post by Chris Rae who provides a macro that converts revisions to standard formatting:

> [Enumerating edits on large documents (AKA converting tracked changes to conventional formatting)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrisrae/2010/05/27/enumerating-edits-on-large-documents-aka-converting-tracked-changes-to-conventional-formatting/)

The macro may not yet do exactly what you need, but it should get you started.

For reference, here is a copy of the macro:

```
Sub EnumerateChanges()
    Dim rAll As Revision
    Dim dReport As Document
    Dim dBigDoc As Document

    Set dBigDoc = ActiveDocument

    If dBigDoc.Revisions.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no revisions in the active document.", vbCritical
    ElseIf MsgBox(“This will enumerate the changes in '" + dBigDoc.Name + "' in a new document and close the original WITHOUT saving changes. Continue?", vbYesNo) <> vbNo Then
        Set dReport = Documents.Add

        dBigDoc.Activate ' really just so we can show progress by selecting the revisions
        dBigDoc.TrackRevisions = False ' Leaving this on results in a disaster

        For Each rAll In dBigDoc.Revisions
            ' Now find the nearest section heading downwards
            Dim rFindFirst As Range, rFindLast As Range
            Set rFindLast = rAll.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range
            While Not IsNumberedPara(rFindLast.Next(wdParagraph))
                Set rFindLast = rFindLast.Next(wdParagraph)
            Wend
            ' Now head back up to the next numbered section header
            Set rFindFirst = rFindLast
            Do
                Set rFindFirst = rFindFirst.Previous(wdParagraph)
            Loop Until IsNumberedPara(rFindFirst) Or (rFindFirst.Previous(wdParagraph) Is Nothing)
            ConvertNumberedToText rFindFirst

            Dim rChangedSection As Range
            Set rChangedSection = dBigDoc.Range(rFindFirst.Start, rFindLast.End)
            ' Properly tag all the revisions in this whole section
            Dim rOnesInThisSection As Revision
            For Each rOnesInThisSection In rChangedSection.Revisions
                rOnesInThisSection.Range.Select ' just for visual update
                DoEvents ' update the screen so we can see how far we are through
                If rOnesInThisSection.Type = wdRevisionDelete Then
                    rOnesInThisSection.Reject
                    With Selection.Range
                        .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
                        .Font.StrikeThrough = True
                    End With
                    dBigDoc.Comments.Add Selection.Range, “deleted”
                Else
                    If rOnesInThisSection.Type = wdRevisionInsert Then
                        rOnesInThisSection.Accept
                        With Selection.Range
                            .Font.ColorIndex = wdBlue
                        End With
                        dBigDoc.Comments.Add Selection.Range, “inserted”
                    End If
                End If
            Next

            ' Now copy the whole thing into our new document
            rChangedSection.Copy
            Dim rOut As Range
            Set rOut = dReport.Range
            rOut.EndOf wdStory, False
            rOut.Paste
        Next rAll

        ' There should end up being no numbered paragraphs at all in the 
        ' new doc (they were converted to text), so delete them
        Dim pFinal As Paragraph
        For Each pFinal In dReport.Paragraphs
            If IsNumberedPara(pFinal.Range) Then
                pFinal.Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers
            End If
        Next

        dBigDoc.Close False
    End If
End Sub

Sub ConvertNumberedToText(rOf As Range)
    If InStr(rOf.ListFormat.ListString, “.”) > 0 Then
        rOf.InsertBefore "Changes to section " + rOf.ListFormat.ListString + " "
    End If
End Sub

Function IsNumberedPara(rOf As Range) As Boolean
    If rOf Is Nothing Then ‘ if the document doesn’t have numbered sections, this will cause changes to be enumerated in the whole thing
        IsNumberedPara = True
    ElseIf rOf.ListFormat.ListString <> "" Then
        If Asc(rOf.ListFormat.ListString) <> 63 Then
            IsNumberedPara = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```